# HTML/CSS tooltip that should appear when hovering over a certain element does not appear

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a tooltip when I hover over text. I tried following [this tutorial by W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_bottom). Whenever I try hover over the text that is supposed to display the tooltip on hover, nothing happens. I've tried to copy-paste W3 Schools' code and it works perfectly.

I've tried centering the text and adding top margins in case the tooltip was off-screen, however that did not fix it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

CSS:

```
#upgradeOne {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip::hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <div class="upgradeDimensions mouse-hand tooltip" id="upgradeOne" onclick="upgradeOneClick()">
          text
            <span class="tooltiptext">
                tooltip text
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the double colon and make it a single :hover. Do you want the tooltip to appear near the text that is being hovered or somewhere else?

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you, I wanted it to appear near it, I had to mess around with some of the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only need one `:` when using `:hover` Next step would be changing the positioning of the **tooltip text**. The first step on that would be to remove the `left: 50%;` on your `.tooltip` `.tooltiptext` CSS.

```css
#upgradeOne {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <div class="upgradeDimensions mouse-hand tooltip" id="upgradeOne" onclick="upgradeOneClick()">
          text
            <span class="tooltiptext">
                tooltip text 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```